# Android gradle - have both debug and release resources in different flavors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources, android-productflavors

I want to be able to set up different things for debug and release versions of my app, for my two flavors. The things I am thinking I need are, app name, app icon, and some strings that are used for keys for various third party libs e.g. Flurry, Crashlytics.

I can get debug to work if I just create a folder called debug, but it will be the same resources for both flavors and I want them for diff flavors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create sourcesets for the build variants.

Suppose you have `vanilla` and `chocolate` product flavors, and `debug` and `release` build types, and you want distinct resources for each combination. Create:

- `src/main/`
- `src/vanillaDebug/`
- `src/chocolateDebug/`
- `src/vanillaRelease/`
- `src/chocolateRelease/`

and put the resources where they need to go.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response Mark, but I now seem to have a problem finding resources. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging says the order should be BuildType -> Flavor -> main -> Dependencies. But I have a resource in releaseVanilla but not in debugVanilla, and I'm getting an error that the resource can't be found. Am I going to have to have the same resources in both debugVanilla AND releaseVanilla? That seems a bit much if 99% of them are the same, and I only need to change two or three strings

Comment: @RussWheeler: Well, the resource has to exist somewhere for the combination of `debug` and `vanilla`. `releaseVanilla` won't cover that. So, either have the resource also defined in `debugVanilla`, or `debug`, or `vanilla`, or `main`.

Comment: @RussWheeler: "That seems a bit much if 99% of them are the same, and I only need to change two or three strings" -- the stuff that is the same goes in sourcesets that describe the scope of "the same", such as `main`. The simplest way to think of this is that one of everything goes in `main`, and then you override in other sourcesets as needed for the "two or three strings".

Comment: So I can have vanilla, debugVanilla, releaseVanilla as folders? Mind blown!

Comment: @RussWheeler: That at least used to work. I haven't tried it in a while.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a go now and put an additional comment on here. Thanks for the answer. Glad to know I'm helping towards that 514k!!

Comment: One final comment, @CommonsWare answer didn't exactly work, the folders needed flavorBuildtype as opposed to buildtypeFlavor e.g. vanillaDebug instead of debugVanilla

Comment: @RussWheeler: My apologies, I was working from memory. I have updated the answer.